# background move to the right

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app and want to make move the background to the right.
The problem that I have is if it moves it does not repeat the background.
I appreciate every suggestion. Thanks.

The code:

```
public class Background
{
    private Bitmap bmp = null;
    private int newWidth = 0;
    private int newHeight = 0;
    private Bitmap bmpScaled = null;
    private int move = 0;
    private float scale = 0;
    private GameView gameView = null;

    public Background(GameView gameView, Bitmap bmp, int x, int y)
    {
        this.gameView = gameView;
        this.bmp = bmp;
        scale = (float) bmp.getHeight() / (float) gameView.getHeight();
        newWidth = Math.round(bmp.getWidth() / scale);
        newHeight = Math.round(bmp.getHeight() / scale);
        bmpScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    }

    private void start()
    {
        move++;
    }

    private void update()
    {
        start();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        update();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmpScaled, move, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat the background you will actually need to call drawBitmap twice.

Consider what would happen if you wanted to repeat a very small background. You would need to tile it several times to cover the area. In this case, you need to tile it twice - once for each screen width.

So it should be something like

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpScaled, move % newWidth, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpScaled, (move % newWidth) - newWidth, 0, null);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "- newWidth" ?

Comment: Yeah. I also wonder if `void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)` would be better, but I'm not too familiar with the deep workings of android and how it handles overdraw.